# Show Dialog when clicking button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image][image]I have two buttons in the form. I want to disable both of these buttons when I press one of these two buttons. And want to show the dialogue modal when I press login button. However, It can't work well in this part. Here is my code!

```
$(function(){
  $(".js-disable-form-individual").on("submit", function() {
    $('.js-disable]-btn').click(function() {                                                                                                         
      $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
    })
  $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
  })  
});
```

Thank you for answering.

Comment: What issue are you facing

Comment: Try `$(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: I only want to show modal dialogue when I push login button and disable these two button in the same time

Comment: I can disable these two button but the modal didn't show when I press login button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your js code to this,

```
$(function(){
  $(".text-center input[type=submit]").on("click", function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();                                                                                                      
    $(".text-center input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
  $('.js-disable-btn').on("click",function(){                                                                                                         
    $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
  });  
  $('#finalSubmit').on("click",function(){                                                                                                         
    $(".js-disable-form-individual").submit();
  });
});
```

*Say if you have a button which id is `finalSubmit` on the dialog (which you want to submit form on click),

Comment: Thank you! But It still can't solve my problem. Because I only want to trigger the button which class is js-disable-btn display modal dialogue.

Comment: I changed into this code it worked. It can disable button and show modal dialogue. However, It can't go to next page

Comment: I've edited my answer..please share your html so that I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, try to separate them?

```
$(function(){
  $(".js-disable-form-individual").on("submit", function() {
     e.preventDefault();     
     $(this).find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
  }) 

  $('.js-disable-btn').on('click',function() {                                                                                                         
      $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
    })
});
```

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault()` to display original submit event